# What is the area of the Quadrilateral

Tags: contest-math, area

[image]
This picture has no further description,from the place I saw. I tried to solve it using Menelaus's Theorem, and I came up to the equation:

$$\frac{1}{CD} \times \frac{AF}{BF}=\frac{AE}{CE} \times \frac{1}{BD}$$

After joining, If we produce AO, then it meets BC at D.

Comment: There is no point $D$ in the diagram

Comment: That is ceva's theorem, as the intersection of AO and BC is D.